# How to generate a simple terrain using for loop [voxel]

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'm trying to generate a 10*10*10 chunk of blocks for my voxel game, rendering 1 block is perfectly fine but when I use a for-loop it messes up, is the following correct?:

```
    final int chunk = 10;
    final float B_SIZE = 1.0f;

    for (int x = 0; x < chunk; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < chunk; y++) {
            for (int z = 0; z < chunk; z++) {
                block.render();
                GL11.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, B_SIZE);
            }
            GL11.glTranslatef(0.0f, B_SIZE, -chunk * B_SIZE);
        }
        GL11.glTranslatef(B_SIZE, -chunk * B_SIZE, 0.0f);
    }
```

p.s: block.render(); is a class where I'm rendering a 1f*1f*1f cube, it also has its own vector3f, that's why I can translate it.

Comment: If it messes up, then no it's not correct.  What are the symptoms?

Comment: It just renders really silly, blocks are shifted 1f higher and 1f to the left, it has a pattern though.

Comment: Maybe you should multiply B_SIZE with 'z', 'y' and 'x' in `GL11.glTranslatef()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start with simpler version. Instead of adjusting the matrix for every block. Push current matrix on the stack. Translate it to draw single block. Then, pop to reset it to original state.

```
final int chunk = 10;
final float B_SIZE = 1.0f;

for (int x = 0; x < chunk; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < chunk; y++) {
        for (int z = 0; z < chunk; z++) {
            GL11.glPushMatrix();
            GL11.glTranslatef(x*B_SIZE, y*B_SIZE, z*B_SIZE);
            block.render();
            GL11.glPopMatrix();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: WOW, I never thought to do that! Thank you very much!